# custom tensorflow layer that inherits another class

Tags: keras, tensorflow

I am trying to make my own custom layer in tensorflow which looks like:

```
class custom_LSTM(RNN):
    # implementation of class
```

where RNN is another class.

However, to use this custom layer in model it needs to inherit `tf.keras.layers.Layer`. I am creating models using `tf.keras`.

Any idea how do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Although I'm not an export of RNN's, the following should work given that RNN is inherited from Layer:

```
from keras.layers import RNN
class custom_LSTM(RNN):
   # implementation of class
   ...
```

It might be good to provide the smallest piece of code that can reproduce your error.